# Bootstrap dropdown adjustment

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-tables, col

I'm trying to adjust the `glyphicon-user icon` and `btn-primary` in dropdown to be displayed properly when the window is resized. However, when I resize the window, my button alignment seems to be out of the window where I can't view the end of the button. Answers anyone?

```
<div class="container-fluid">
         <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                       <strong>User</strong>
                    </a>
                    <ul id="user-dp" class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li>
                                    <div class="row">
                                    <!-- Login -->
                                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                                        <p class="text-center">
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user icon-size"></span>
                                        </p>
                                        </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-8">
                                        <p class="text-left"><strong>Test</strong></p>
                                        <p class="text-left">
                                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-sm">Testing</a>
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                        <div class="bottom text-center">
                                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-block">Test again</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
          </ul>
</div>
```

## style.css

```
.icon-size
{
    margin-top:5%;
    font-size: 87px;
}
#user-dp{
    min-width: 300px;
    padding: 14px 14px 0;
    overflow:hidden;
    background-color:rgba(255,255,255,.8);
}
#user-dp .help-block{
    font-size:12px    
}
#user-dp .bottom{
    background-color:rgba(255,255,255,.8);
    border-top:1px solid #ddd;
    clear:both;
    padding:14px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jamdev's answer is close, but it's your `#user-dp` that sets the min-width. This will keep your box 300px wide no matter the window size. By adding the following CSS, you will reset the min-width to 0 whenever your window is under 768px wide.

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    #user-dp { 
        min-width:0; 
    } 
}
```

Demo: http://www.bootply.com/GetuidWvdM

Answer (score 0):

add this code into your custom.css `@media (max-width: 767px) .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu { min-width:0; }`

Comment: if I remove it, the buttons and icon become too close to each other if I didn't resize the window

Comment: I've fixed the first answer :)

Comment: I have added @media (max-width: 800px) {

.navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu { 
 min-width:0; 
 }

}. But it doesn't seem to be working